# Rails scope for parent records that do not have particular child records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a parent model Effort that has_many split_times:

```
class Effort
  has_many :split_times
end

class SplitTime
  belongs_to :effort
  belongs_to :split
end

class Split
  has_many :split_times
  enum kind: [:start, :finish, :intermediate]
end
```

I need a scope that will return efforts that do not have a start split_time. This seems like it should be possible, but so far I'm not able to do it.

I can return efforts with no split_times with this:

```
scope :without_split_times, -> { includes(:split_times).where(split_times: {:id => nil}) }
```

And I can return efforts that have at least one split_time with this:

```
scope :with_split_times, -> { joins(:split_times).uniq }
```

Here's my attempt at the scope I want:

```
scope :without_start_time, -> { joins(split_times: :split).where(split_times: {:id => nil}).where('splits.kind != ?', Split.kinds[:start]) }
```

But that doesn't work. I need something that will return all efforts that do not have a split_time that has a split with kind: :start even if the efforts have other split_times. I would prefer a Rails solution but can go to raw SQL if necessary. I'm using Postgres if it matters.

Comment: You can try left join: `Effort.joins('LEFT JOIN split_times ON split_times.effort_id = efforts.id').where('split_times.id IS NULL')`

Comment: @user3309314 That returns only efforts that have no split_times at all. I want to return efforts that have split_times so long as none of the split_times relate to a start split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can left join on your criteria (i.e. `splits.kind = 'start'`) which will include nulls (i.e. there was no matching row to join). The difference is that Rails' `join` will by default give you an inner join (there are matching rows in both tables) but you want a left join as you need to check that there is no matching row on the right table.

With the results of that join you can group by event and then count the number of matching splits - if it's 0 then there are no matching start splits for that event!

This might do the trick for you:

```
scope :without_start_time, -> { 
  joins("LEFT JOIN split_times ON split_times.effort_id = efforts.id").
    joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN splits ON split_times.split_id = splits.id " \
          "AND splits.kind = 0").
    group("efforts.id").
    having("COUNT(splits.id) = 0")
}
```

Comment: This syntax is wrong in a couple of places, but even after fixing things, it returns a relation consisting of thousands of Effort records where it should be returning just a handful. Here's the SQL: `SELECT  "efforts".* FROM "efforts" INNER JOIN "split_times" ON "split_times"."effort_id" = "efforts"."id" LEFT JOIN splits ON split_times.split_id = splits.id AND splits.kind = 0 WHERE "splits"."id" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]`

Comment: @moveson      My bad, that would have matched everything that has _any_ splits that aren't a "start" instead of where _none_ of the splits are a "start". I've updated my answer with a more appropriate solution now.

Comment: This is close. It returns efforts that have split_times so long as none of the split_times are start split_times. But it should also return efforts that have no split_times at all, and it doesn't do that.

Comment: @moveson This is resolved by changing the left join to a left outer join, and inner join to a left join - updated!